# how to aggregate group in mongoengine python

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to aggregate `group` in `MongoDB`.

We are using `Python`, `django`, `Rest framework` and `Mongoengine`.

This is how my model looks like:

```
class TestSnapshot(EmbeddedDocument):
    identifier = StringField()
name = StringField()
created = DateTimeField(
    default = datetime.datetime.now)

class Test(Document):
    agreement = ReferenceField(Agreement)
history = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(TestSnapshot))
created = DateTimeField(
    default = datetime.datetime.now)
```

In my view:

```
test = models.Test.objects.filter(agreement__in = agreements).aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$created"
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$created"
    }
}])
print test
```

But I got a trackback like this:

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u 'test'), ('pipeline', [{
    '$match': {
        'agreement': {
            '$in': [ObjectId('558b150a89f4ad3f33ebb8ae')]
        }
    }
    },
    [{
    '$unwind': '$created'
    }, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$created'
    }
    }]
]), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace noq.$cmd failed: exception: pipeline element 1 is not an object
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to `python` with `mongo`.
 Thanks for helping :)

Best regards,
Johnny

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the problem, I was doing the aggregate wrong.

```
models.Test.objects.filter(agreement__in = agreements).aggregate(
  {"$group": { "_id": "$created" }}
)
```

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You tried list inside aggregate. That was the mistake. You can give broad answer if you can. That will help others.